# Register Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate 3DS at Club Nintendo

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, monster-hunter-3-ultimate, club-nintendo

I bought a (european) 3DS and Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate two days ago (bought seperately, no bundle) and want to take advantage of [this current running promotion](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Misc-/Campaigns/Monster-Hunter-Gift-Hunt-Together-Promotion/Monster-Hunter-Gift-Hunt-Together-Promotion-760515.html) where it says

> If you register Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate (Nintendo 3DS version) with Club Nintendo before 22:59 (UK time) on 30th June, you’ll be able to receive a Recommendation Code which you can pass along to a friend. If your friend registers a Nintendo 3DS or Nintendo 3DS XL system between 23:01 (UK time) on 3rd June and 22:59 (UK time) on 31st July 2013, and enters the Recommendation Code before 22:59 (UK time) on 5th August 2013, he/she will be eligible to receive a free Download Code for Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate on Nintendo 3DS!

I want to give a friend who also bought a new 3DS a copy of the game, but I fail to understand how to register my game to my Club Nintendo account.

It did not come with a leaflet with a code printed on. 
I ordered it online and the game case was still originally sealed, I don't think there's any way someone took it.

How can I register my copy of Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate at Club Nintendo?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work for me.

Comment: Link worked fine for me.  FireFox 21.0, Windows XP

Comment: Sorry I screwed up and updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game should have come with a leaflet that has the code on the back. You're not completely out of luck though, because I found [this in the FAQs](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/club/en/faq.jsp?menu=surveys&submenu=clubn-faq-reg-survey-game-no-pin) on the Club Nintendo website:

---

**My Game Didn't Come With a PIN Code. How Can I Register My Game?**

Answer:

If the game you purchased is [eligible](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/club/en/faq.jsp?menu=products&submenu=clubn-faq-eligible-which-products) for registration and the card with the PIN code is missing, please [contact us](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/webform.jsp) and provide your name, username, email address, and the game title you're inquiring about.

---

That question is on the North American Club Nintendo. You can select 'Other' > 'UK & Ireland' for your country, but if you're using the UK Club Nintendo website you should [contact support with this form](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Contact/Contact/Contact-Form-106282.html).

Comment: That's for the US Club Nintendo. OP is talking about the EU Club Nintendo, which is a different system, and this question is not in [their FAQ](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/club_nintendo/faq/support_6.html). [Contacting them](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Contact/Contact-621598.html) is still the best bet, but the procedure might be different.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know if there should be a card or not or if I just go nuts not knowing how to register it. I contacted the EU support through its support forms. There's a category just for this. http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Contact/Contact/Contact-Form-106282.html

Comment: Good point Michael. I'll update my answer to reflect that. Glad I could help elch, I hope they resolve it for you soon.